# Center an image inside a div?

Tags: css, centering

I have an image inside a div like this

```
<div><img /><div>
```

The image is dynamic of no fixed size. The div is of size `200px by 200px`. The image size is not known beforehand. If the size of the image is greater than `190px by 190px`, set it to `190px by 190px` (that is, `max-width:190px`, `max-height:190px`). How can I center the image with these needs satisfied? I need a solution working in Internet Explorer 7 too.

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237636/how-to-center-image-inside-div) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238759/center-an-image-inside-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically) can not be applied to my problem because

1. It is not certain that the image would be less than 200 pixels.
2. I want horizontal alignment too.
3. No Internet Explorer 7 support.

(Some questions have been asked on Stack Overflow regarding the same, but my scenario is different, so they are not applicable for this particular problem.)

Comment: is using jQuery to calculate and center okay with you?

Comment: @DexterHuinda Can't use jQuery, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to change the `div` into a table.  Normally, you shouldn't use tables for positioning, but when it comes to older non-standards-compliant browsers, sometimes that's the only choice.  [Demonstration here](http://jsfiddle.net/nhqsQ/). For the record, this works on Internet Explorer 6, as well.

Code:

**CSS**

```
#theDiv
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#theImg
{
    max-width: 190px;
    max-height: 190px;
}​
```

**​HTML**

```
<table id="theDiv" style="border: solid 1px #000">
    <tr>
        <td>
    <img id="theImg" src="http://cdn1.sbnation.com/community_logos/9156/gangreen-small.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's an [update](http://jsfiddle.net/nhqsQ/11/) that uses CSS instead of changing the markup to an actual table:

```
#theDiv
{
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#theImg
{
    max-width: 190px;
    max-height: 190px;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td { 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

<div id="theDiv" style="border: solid 1px #000">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
    <img id="theImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Form shouldn't trump function — it's bad practice to use a table for layout in this day and age in professional web-development, especially if there are other alternatives.

Comment: Though all answers had working examples. I had problem making them work in my code. This did.

Comment: Here's [an update](http://jsfiddle.net/nhqsQ/10/) that uses CSS instead of changing the markup to be a table element.

Answer (score 2):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ANwmv/

Solution to centering as suggested in: http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html

```
<style type="text/css">
.wraptocenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.wraptocenter img { max-width: 190px; max-height: 190px; }
.wraptocenter * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*\*//*/
.wraptocenter {
    display: block;
}
.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}
/**/
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 8]><style>
.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
</style><![endif]-->
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wraptocenter"><span></span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="..."></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent  a *line-height* equivalent to its own height, and a *text-align* property of center. Give the image a *vertical-align* property of middle to centre it within its line-height:

**HTML:**

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.waleoyediran.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/stackoverflow.png"/>                
            </div>
        </body>   
    </html>
```

**CSS:**

```
div, img {
 border: 1px solid black;  
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

img {
  max-width: 190px;
  max-height: 190px;
  vertical-align: middle;    
}
```

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/WEpet/)

Comment: @AlexW: Why is that? Forget CSS for a minute. Using a `<table>` is marking up that content as tabular, which it isn't. A `<div>` is semantically meaningless. Line-height will only affect inline elements, which includes images (for a reason, IMO). I'd be interested to hear why you think that's bad practice?

Comment: @AlexW Actually Alex, I have to disagree. From the W3C spec: "On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, **'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.**" (emphasis added. Source: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height). An image is an inline element just like any other, and it's the height of the 'line box' as they put that gets set.  Using the `line-height` property in this way is perfectly valid and certainly not "misusing" it.

Comment: @AlexW No, that's incorrect. "Any images within the paragraph should increase the height of the line-box so that they fit within the line box." (source: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS1/current/test44.htm) All elements in the page are either block or inline elements. Images are inline elements (though can be forced to render like block elements.)

Comment: Again from W3C: "Inline-level elements are those elements of the source document that do not form new blocks of content; the content is distributed in lines (e.g., emphasized pieces of text within a paragraph, **inline images**, etc.)." (my emphasis; http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes)

Comment: @AlexW No, it's not a by-product. It has been designed in this way. CSS doesn't carry any semantics to the elements that it's used on — it's stylistic. You're proposed solution of tables does however. And no, the `letter-spacing` property doesn't do that: "The letter-spacing property specifies **spacing behavior between text characters**" (http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/letter-spacing). The `text-align` property certainly though: "The text-align property describes how **inline-level content of a block container is aligned**." (http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/text-align).

Comment: @AlexW Well I'll just finish by replying that I think function should *always* trump form: precisely the reason that we've separated stylesheets from the semantic markup of the HTML itself to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
<div style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;"> 
    <img style="margin:0 auto" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` is setting the top margin to 0px.  You should be using `margin: auto;`

Comment: The zero does no harm, but it will of course not have any effect since the img remains inline.