# Center an image inside

Tags: html, css, alignment

I need to center an image, at least horizontally, without using tables and workable on at least Internet Explorer 8. (Internet Explorer 7 too if possible).

I need a solution similar to an earlier asked question on Stack Overflow, *[Center an image inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284637/center-an-image-inside-a-div)*, but doing it using tables, which is not acceptable solution here.

I tried a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7LJx/) with "margin:0px auto", which work for all other elements, but it is not working for an image. Quick code is as follows.

#### HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <img src="https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-ash4/195658_100001734379625_1121483775_q.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
.outer{
    width:300px;
    border:1px #000 solid;
    padding:5px;
}.outer img{
    border:1px #F00 solid;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Is there any pure CSS solution, if possible but not necessarily, applicable for Internet Explorer 7 too?

Comment: as @Mehmet answered: add to `.outer{ /*this*/ text-align:center;
 }` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add text-align:center; into .outer class.

```
.outer{
    width:300px;
    border:1px #000 solid;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Didn't thought text-align might work for images too.

Comment: Thanks for help. Sure I'll after 15 mins waiting time is over. +1 for quick help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center both vertically and horizontally:

```
.outer{
    width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    border:1px #000 solid;
    padding:5px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.outer img{
    border:1px #F00 solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M7LJx/1/

**Note** `display: table-cell` will not work on IE7 though.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the CSS code:

```
.outer{
    width:300px;
    border:1px #000 solid;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.outer img {
    border:1px #F00 solid;
}
```

It works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If your img must be display:block, then you must use margin:0 auto; because, text-align:center; will not work for block element.

But, if your img is display:inline; (or not set, so default is inline), then text-align will work.